# laravel and apache mod_status

Tags: php, laravel, apache, laravel-5

I have enabled Apache mod_status on my server:

```
OS: centos 6
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
php version 7.1
```

I get a 404 error page for **example.com/server-status** as i dont know how can i serv this route, with laravel(5.2) route api or any other way?
my configuration in httpd.conf:

```
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1
    Allow from .example.com
    Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx #my ip address
</Location>
```

and in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status
```

Comment: seems you need to modify the url rewrite on `public` directory. your 404 gives laravel 404 right?

Comment: apparently, you need to remove the `=` on `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status`. and put it before [line 20](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess#L20). see [example](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=3e97d53b-2df3-5dd8-8ecc-970ec779c77d)

Comment: @BagusTesa thanks alot, you saved my day with provided htaccess test tools. you can post it as an answer and i will accept it

Comment: your welcome. glad be of help~

Answer (score 3):

I use the following code on my .htaccess to server-info and server-status:

```
RewriteRule ^(server-info|server-status) - [L]
```

Make sure first you get server-info and server-status working.
Them, read the logs about permission issues (mostly are because of order from rules).

My system:

- Laravel 6
- Apache 2.4.1
- FreeBSD 12.1

Answer (score 1):

Try placing it inside the virtualhost tag

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin tecmint@example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com
ServerName example.com
ErrorLog logs/example.com-error_log
CustomLog logs/example.com-access_log common
<Location /server-status>
SetHandler server-status
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
Allow from example.com 
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```